# JQuery UI - Drag from Sortable to Droppable

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a list of images which are sortable. To delete them, the user will drag them from the Sortable list to a Droppable div representing a trashcan. How can I accomplish this?

Do I need to add a draggable to each of the image for it to work with the droppable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978164/2333214) seems to provide faulty information. For anyone referring to this post in future,

From [rjmunro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3408/rjmunro)'s comment for the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978164/2333214) -

> Sortables are already draggable. There's no need to explicitly declare them as draggable.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LVtwD/)

From [JQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) -

> By default, sortable items share draggable properties.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, each image needs to be draggable (even though it is already sortable).

An item needs to be draggable so that you can drop it on your droppable area.

jQuery has a nice demo of how to make Sortable and Draggable items play nicely together:

[jQuery UI - Draggable Demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable)