# jQuery UI from sortable to free drag around

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm very new to jQuery UI. 
I need to have list (sortable) from which I can drag elements to a other div. In that div the element needs to have a specific width and height. The element also needs to be limited to drag around within the div or the list. I have tried a couple of things and red the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) but I can't figure it out jet.

This is what I have tried:

1. [JQuery UI - Drag from Sortable to Droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978119/jquery-ui-drag-from-sortable-to-droppable)
2. http://jsfiddle.net/LVtwD/
3. [Drag from sortable to droppable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995785/drag-from-sortable-to-droppable)
4. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

The code that I currently have is the following:
The js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#available').sortable();
    $('#available').disableSelection();

    $('#used').droppable({
        accept: '#available li',
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
           $("<div></div>").html(ui.draggable.html()).appendTo(this);
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul id="available">
                <li style="width: 45px; height: 20px; background: #a0d3e8; border: 1px solid #74bfdd;"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="used" style="width: 400px; height: 500px; border:1px solid #222;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know that I can limit the movement of a div within a div with:
`containment: "parent"`
The reason I have inline CSS is because these values of width and height are variable.

The problems I have are the following. When an element from the list is dragged to the div it is added as a list item instead of a div. Also the width and height completely disappear.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wherever your new `li`s are coming from, it's not from the code posted. As for the style properties, they're not there because you're not copying them across. This works exactly as you'd expect it: http://jsfiddle.net/fdmvoL73/

Comment: The reason I only added one `li` is because it doesn't matter for the question. In the fiddle you showed how to copy over the css, thanks for that. But you didn't show how to move around the div.

Comment: Can you include a more detailed description of what you expect? In the fiddle, a `li` is dragged, and is replaced with a `div` on `drop`, which is exactly what the question asks about. But the previous comment makes me think you might want something else?

Comment: @blgt Yes infact I want some more. I have fiddled around a bit more and I got closer of what I want. In the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4y51L4wm/3/ there is an updated version of my javascript. I almost got what I want. There should also be a possibility to drag the `li` element back to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is whith what I came up with.

```
$(function() {
    $('#available').sortable();
    $('#available').disableSelection();

    $('.draggable').draggable({ containment: '#used' });
});
```